# EasyVPN vs Site to Site VPN bandwidth use

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, ios, site-to-site-vpn

We have recently switched from site-to-site VPNs to EasyVPNs.  At around the same time, we noticed increased bandwidth use.  Does anyone know whether these two VPN methods use noticeably different bandwidths?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any significant bandwidth.  EasyVPN just works more like a client side VPN with a remote box requesting an IPSEC tunnel with a central client, whereas with Site 2 Site either side can initiate the connection.  Otherwise both are exactly the same.

Maybe your previous config had a problem, and could only be initiated by the central hib, and the central hub didn't need to set up connections, wheras now you are responding effectively to the demand from your remote sites.